# What will be the best ways to improve the scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, nestedrecyclerview

I am having a parent recycler view with vertical rows, where odd rows of recycler view are header views and even rows are again recycler views with horizontal scrolling. What are the best ways to improve scrolling such that all the vertical scrolls are received by the parent and the horizontal scrolls if on the even rows are received by the child recycler views without affecting the parent?

Comment: What have you done yet? Could you provide your sample code?

Comment: @Billy doesnt have much understanding about intercepting touch events.. trying to figure it out

Comment: Hope this documentation could help:[Manage touch events in a ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup)